# Monitorar abertura de Forms C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arquitetura-de-software

Estou precisando monitorar a abertura de Forms dentro de uma aplicação C#. Por exemplo, toda vez que abrir um Form dentro da aplicação, a aplicação deve executar um método ou dispara um evento com informações do form aberto. Eu pesquisei e achei este código:

```
public class BaseForm : Form
{
public BaseForm()
{
    if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime) return;
    this.Load += BaseForm_Load;
    this.FormClosed += BaseForm_FormClosed;
}
private IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(Control control)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAllControls(ctrl)).Concat(controls);
}
void BaseForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Log(string.Format("{0} Closed", this.Name));
}
void BaseForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Log(string.Format("{0} Opened", this.Name));
    GetAllControls(this).OfType<Button>().ToList()
        .ForEach(x => x.Click += ButtonClick);
}
void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    if (button != null) Log(string.Format("{0} Clicked", button.Name));
}
public void Log(string text)
{
    var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "log.txt");
    text = string.Format("{0} - {1}", DateTime.Now, text);
    System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(file, new string[] { text });
}
```

Segundo o autor, todos os *forms* devem derivar deste `BaseForm`.

Esta abordagem seria a mais viável?

Existem formas mas apropriadas para monitorar a abertura de *forms* dentro de uma aplicação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não posso falar em detalhes, não sei se ele é adequado ao que precisa e se conseguirá adaptar ao que precisa, é provável que tenha mais coisas do que precisa, e não gosto do estilo de codificação dele, mas isso é problema meu :)

Pelo que descreveu me parece que a técnica básica é essa mesmo. Com a herança garante que todos formulários possuem a lógica necessária para fazer a notificação do que aconteceu. O uso dos eventos específicos determina o que monitorar.

Como fará a notificação, pra quem, do que, e o que deve ser notificado é algo que você pode mudar para sua necessidade, mas essa é uma boa base.

Obviamente ela tem o defeito de não funcionar se alguém não derivar dessa classe, mas isso seria um erro maior no desenvolvimento.

A outra forma que eu vejo que é mais seguro é usar programação orientada a aspectos. Mas duvido que seja uma opção melhor, até por ser difícil para a maioria das pessoas.

Comment: Obrigado pelos comentários, eles me ajudaram a resolver o problema.